# Testing for a length

Tags: tex-core

I'm trying to write some code, that tests whether a value is a length or something else. I've found `\token_if_dim_register` and `\token_if_skip_register` which seems to do the trick, but can not get this to work, probably because of lacking LaTeX knowledge. :-)

I put together the following small snippet to illustrate my problem:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\iflengthx}{mmm}
{
\token_if_dim_register:NTF#1{#2}{#3}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\iflengthx{20pt}{ islen}{ notlen}
\end{document}
```

It outputs `pt islen notlen`, repeating characters of the first argument, which I do not understand. Any suggestions to what I'm doing wrong?

**Update 1:**

After receiving a few comments here, I decided to go for a more simplistic approach, not as 'foolproof' is I'd like, but it will do the job.

I simply test (using xstring) if the string is number without the last two characters (assuming the unit is always two characters, i.e. mm, pt, etc.). If this shortened string is a decimal, but the full string isn't, I accept this a proof the value is a length (to be used for \addtolength).

Here is my implementation, for anyone who encounters a similar problem.

```
\newcommand\islength[3]
{
  \IfDecimal{#1}
  {#3}
  {\StrGobbleRight{#1}{2}[\tmp]\IfDecimal{\tmp}{#2}{#3}}
}
```

**Update 2:**

I could't resist, so I improved this a bit. First I test for a valid unit in the end, then for a valid decimal values in the remaining string:

```
\newcommand\islength[3]
{
  \StrRight{#1}{2}[\unt]
  \IfSubStr{pt mm cm in ex em mu}{\unt}
  {
    \StrGobbleRight{#1}{2}[\val]
    \IfDecimal{\val}{#2}{#3}
  }
  {#3}
}
```

Comment: `20pt` is 4 character tokens, and certainly not a `\dimen` register.  Moreover, you are calling `\token_if_dim_register:NTF` in an incorrect way: the `N` means the first argument is a single token, but your `#1` contains 4 tokens (`2`, `0`, `p` and `t`). This implies that `0`, `p` and `t` will feed the other arguments of `\token_if_dim_register:NTF`, which was clearly not intended. In order to get helpful replies, you should probably tell more about the context (why you need such a test). In your call, the true branch is `0`, the false branch `p` and the rest not ...

Comment: ...  seen by `\token_if_dim_register:NTF`, that is why you see `p` followed  by `t islen notlen` (since it was left in the input stream after `\token_if_dim_register:NTF` did its work).

Comment: Do you expect that `#1` is *anything* that TeX understands as a dimension, including `0.5\textwidth` or `\dimexpr...\relax`? Note that in your case you're passing `{2}{0}{p}` to `\token_if_dim_register:NTF`; the test returns false, so you get `pt islen notlen`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can see that I clearly misunderstood what I've been messing around with.

I want to create a new command that takes a variable number of arguments (have this part sorted) Each of these can be either a length (i.e. 20pt) or code (a single letter). I want to get a sum of the arguments that represent a length. I can easily add the lengths together (using \addtolength) but I need to identify which arguments are valid lengths. Hence the need for a command that test this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regular expression facilities of `expl3`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\iflengthTF}{mmm}
 {
  % regex from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23872060/923955
  % with modifications for expl3 and for adding a unit
  \regex_match:nnTF
   { \A [+\-]? ((\d+(\.\d*)?)|(\.\d+)) \s* (pt|pc|in|bp|cm|mm|dd|cc|sp|ex|em) \Z} % regex
   { #1 } % test string
   { #2 } % true text
   { #3 } % false text
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\iflengthTF{20pt}{islen}{notlen}

\iflengthTF{20.2cm}{islen}{notlen}

\iflengthTF{-20.2cm}{islen}{notlen}

\iflengthTF{.2 em}{islen}{notlen}

\iflengthTF{-.2em}{islen}{notlen}

\iflengthTF{20. cm}{islen}{notlen}

\iflengthTF{Hello}{islen}{notlen}

\end{document}
```

All lines but the last print `islen`.