# Passing a token list variable as an argument

Tags: macros, latex3, arguments, token-lists

The code below parses out a comma-delimited bit of an argument, then passes that bit to a function, as a token list variable. It works, by using `\exp_args:Neee`, but I suspect that there's a better way.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{intfig} {
  > { \SplitArgument { 1 } { , } } m  O{} }
{
  \group_begin:
    
  % Certain things are hard to do using a clist, so it's held as a seq too.
  \clist_set:Nn \l_intfig_optclist_clist { #2 }
  \seq_set_from_clist:NN \l_intfig_optseq_seq { \l_intfig_optclist_clist }
  
  % The first of the optional arguments might be a length.
  \seq_get_left:NN \l_intfig_optseq_seq \l_intfig_firstvalue_tl

  \exp_args:Neee \iflengthTF \l_intfig_firstvalue_tl {TRUE}{FALSE} \\
  
  \group_end:
}{}

% Taken from 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498976/testing-for-a-length
\NewDocumentCommand{\iflengthTF}{mmm}
 {
  will\ regexp\ #1 \\
  \regex_match:nnTF
   { \A [+\-]? ((\d+(\.\d*)?)|(\.\d+)) \s* (pt|pc|in|bp|cm|mm|dd|cc|sp|ex|em) \Z} % regex
   { #1 } % test string
   { #2 } % true text
   { #3 } % false text
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{intfig}{blather,1.2in}[14pt,more,another]
  random body
\end{intfig}

\end{document}
```

Admittedly, my understanding of what's going here is limited, but there's a token list variable in `\l_int_fig_firstvalue_tl`. That variable can't be passed as-is to `\iflengthTF` because it's "unexpanded," if that's the right term (it's boxed or wrapped or a psuedo-pointer).

Using `\exp_args:Neee` to expand the argument does the trick, but is there a more direct way to convert variables to their contents?

Comment: `\exp_args:NV`?

Comment: Yes, that works. For some reason, I was trying to use Nv, not NV. These distinctions elude me.

Comment: The `V` specification receives an unbraced token (and leaves the braced value in place), with the `v` you'd pass a braced control sequence name to retrieve the same value. So it'd be `\exp_args:Nv \iflengthTF { l_intfig_firstvalue_tl } ...`.

Comment: But you are better served with egreg's answer than with just that small adjustment.  ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define your own conditional and a variant thereof, rather than using a document level command.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{intfig} { > { \SplitArgument { 1 } { , } } m  O{} }
 {
  % Certain things are hard to do using a clist, so it's held as a seq too.
  \clist_set:Nn \l_intfig_optclist_clist { #2 }
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_intfig_optseq_seq { #2 }
  
  % The first of the optional arguments might be a length.
  \seq_get_left:NN \l_intfig_optseq_seq \l_intfig_firstvalue_tl

  \intfig_if_length:VTF \l_intfig_firstvalue_tl {TRUE}{FALSE} \\
 }
 {}

% Taken from 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498976/testing-for-a-length

\prg_new_protected_conditional:Nnn \intfig_if_length:n { T, F, TF }
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF
   { \A [+\-]? ((\d+(\.\d*)?)|(\.\d+)) \s* (pt|pc|in|bp|cm|mm|dd|cc|sp|ex|em) \Z} % regex
   { #1 } % test string
   { \prg_return_true: }
   { \prg_return_false: }
 }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \intfig_if_length:n { V } { T, F, TF }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{intfig}{blather,1.2in}[14pt,more,another]
  random body
\end{intfig}

\begin{intfig}{blather,1.2in}[oops,more,another]
  random body
\end{intfig}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same result with a slightly different approach, using directly `#2` via `\clist_item:nn` and `e`-expansion prior to do the conditional check:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{intfig} { > { \SplitArgument { 1 } { , } } m  O{} }
 {
  % Certain things are hard to do using a clist, so it's held as a seq too.
  %\clist_set:Nn \l_intfig_optclist_clist { #2 }
  %\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_intfig_optseq_seq { #2 }
  
  \intfig_if_length:eTF { \clist_item:nn { #2 } { 1 } } {TRUE}{FALSE} \\
 }
 {}

% Taken from 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498976/testing-for-a-length

\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \intfig_if_length:n { T, F, TF }
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF
   { \A [+\-]? ((\d+(\.\d*)?)|(\.\d+)) \s* (pt|pc|in|bp|cm|mm|dd|cc|sp|ex|em) \Z} % regex
   { #1 } % test string
   { \prg_return_true: }
   { \prg_return_false: }
 }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \intfig_if_length:n { V,e } { T, F, TF }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{intfig}{blather,1.2in}[14pt,more,another]
  random body
\end{intfig}

\begin{intfig}{blather,1.2in}[oops,more,another]
  random body
\end{intfig}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `protected_conditional`? (given `\regex_match:nn`)

Comment: @gusbrs You're perfectly right!

Comment: Thanks for both of these answers. The clouds are clearing...gradually.